# Posso Fazer um CRUD dentro do VSCode?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, crud

**Olá Pessoas**, estou começando a aprender um pouco de **banco de dados** com a linguagem de programação principal sendo **JAVA**, e sempre é falado sobre o **CRUD**(*Create, Read, Update and Delete*) estava dando uma olhada em alguns vídeos e sempre é usado uma IDE (*NetBeans ou Eclipse*)

Minha Pergunta boba é!

**Posso fazer um CRUD utilizando o VSCODE como IDE?**

(adoro o vscode)

```
                                                                        Obrigado pela atenção.
```

Answer (score -2):

Bom dia Carlos, pode sim, porém o NetBeans e Eclipse, já possuem paletas de componentes para montar uma tela com o framework Spring que te possibilita essa facilidade, ao contrário no VS Code que terá que fazer manual, até onde sei.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

você consegue fazer um crud até com um bloco de notas! A diferença é o trabalho necessário para fazer o mesmo.

O VS Code é um editor de códigos, o que significa que ele é um "bloco de notas" com plugins que permitem compilar os códigos. No entanto, ele se difere de uma IDE (NetBeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ etc.) pois uma IDE além de editar códigos, ela possui a documentação da linguagem e tenta prever o que você quer fazer, verificando erros em tempo de desenvolvimento e indicando melhorias.

Dessa forma, uma IDE é extremamente recomendada em projetos mais complexos, inclusive para um CRUD.

O fato dos vídeos usarem em maioria o Eclipse é porque ele é uma IDE mais antiga e consolidada no mercado, além de ter muitos plugins que permitem integrações com diferentes softwares (como o Tomcat).